# Invoking Eloquent method through Reflaction Class, Method not found error

Tags: php, laravel, exception, reflection, eloquent

I'm invoking the modal method by `ReflactionClass` as given below code,

```php
public static function get($class = 'App/Tag'){
    $modal = new ReflectionClass($class);
    if($modal->hasMethod('all')){
        $data = $modal->getMethod('all')->invoke($modal);
        return (json_encode($data));
    }else{
        throw new MethodNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

The above given function works fine and fetches all data using eloquent's **`all()`** method. But when i tried to fetch modal along with relationship, I faced the method **`withCount`** not found. There the error prone code.

```php
public static function get($class = 'App/Tag' , $cnt = true){
    $modal = new ReflectionClass($class);
    if($modal->hasMethod('get') && ($cnt ? $modal->hasMethod('withCount') : true)){
        $data = $modal->getMethod('withCount')->invokeArgs($modal, ['product'])->getMethod('get')->invoke($modal);
        return (json_encode($data));
    }else{
        throw new MethodNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to fetch the modal with count of `product` relationship using Reflaction.

Check this table [image: Schema], having the `details` column containing class name, relation etc. I'm re-creating it using refraction and details given in row.

Comment: because `withCount` isn't a Model method, it is on `Eloquent\Builder` ... why are you going about this in this way in the first place?

Comment: I have a class name `string` stored in the database, I have to bring that up and count the number of relationship modal it has, that's why I'm using reflection. Is there a similar workaround to sort out the problem statement?

Comment: why is the class name in the database? trying to figure out what problem you were solving by putting the class name in the database

Comment: I have a kind of datatype table, contains a definition about class, input fields, type, relationship, etc. please check the image I'm attaching to the question.

Comment: you seem to know that these are 'models' so you dont need to do any of those checks, just get a new instance of that class and go .... `$model = new $class; $res = $model->withCount('products')->get();`

Comment: but how do I get the instance of the model? I mean, I just have a model (with namespace) in string format. What if I want to run the query similar to `Model::with(['relation'])->where(['data_type_id' => 1])->first()`?

Comment: `$model = new $class;` `$model = app($class);` `$class::where(...)->first();` etc

Comment: now see, if I have `$class = 'App/Role';` and I call `$modal = new $class` it will work okay but is gonna create a new instance of that modal class, I don't want that, I want  to call it's static methods like `with`. If you have any example, please post.

Comment: i provided that example `$class::where(...)->first();` .. even these 'static' method calls are creating new instances of the model in the background, and `with` isn't a static method, it is a regular method ... `__callStatic` is in play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the class name you want to use and know it is a Model. You can get new instances of that class yourself or make static calls to the class just by having the class name as a string:

```
$model = new $class;

$model = app($class); // using the application container to resolve the class

$res = $model->where(...)->withCount(...)->get();

// static call syntax
$res = $class::withCount(...)->where(...)->get();
```

Good luck with your project, it looks interesting.